# Nonlinear approximation of 1D signal using Contourlet transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

We know that contourlet transform is a 2-dimensional transform which is able to capture the geometric information present in the signal. The IEEE paper "The contourlet transform: an efficient directional multiresolution image representation by Minh N. Do and Martin vetterli" explains in detail about the contourlet transforms and its construction. The authors have also provided the Matlab toolbox in the link "https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8837-contourlet-toolbox".

The problem with which I am stuck at is- How can we represent a 1D signal using a few of these contourlet coefficients.

The complete description goes like this: Suppose I have 1000 data points (x,y) in a text file or in excel file representing a circle/ellipse. With this data, I plot a curve in the X-Y plane. Now I want to represent this whole curve with a few number of data points in some transformed domain such as Fourier/wavelet/contourlet domains. The way we proceed with Fourier and wavelet bases is, we construct a 1D complex signal x+i*y and take its 1D Fourier or wavelet transform. Then we keep only the top "M" coefficients and reconstruct the signal using only these "M" coefficients. I was trying to extend the same logic to the contourlet transforms also. The problem then being faced is how can we use Contourlets for such an analysis since I have a 1D signal but my transform is 2D. I am using the contourlet toolbox as provided in the link above. Is there any other way to proceed with this problem ???

It would be nice if the solution is provided in terms of the usage of the functions provided in the toolbox for this problem.

Comment: Can't you just create a 2D image and plot those x, y points on it, then apply contourlet decomposition (pdfbdec) as shown in decdemo.m ?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Why do you want to apply something specifically designed for 2D to a 1D signal?

Comment: @Cris Consider a simple case in which I want to see how Contourlets performs with respect to wavelets and Fourier transforms in terms of non-linear approximation or noise reduction.

Comment: @ dhanushika  If I create a 2D image from the plots and then save it, I will get an image with the x and y-axis along with the numbers marked on them.  Is this what you meant in your reply? Is there an alternate way of only getting the plot? Anyway, it would be preferable if I could only use the data (not an image constructed from the data) to find its nonlinear approximation.

Comment: @hrishitoshbisht Since contourlets are specific to 2D, you should do that comparison in 2D. Even if you fudge something to get it to work in 1D, it won't be a fair or meaningful comparison. The contourlet paper talks about orientation and curvature. You don't have those in 1D.

Comment: I mean something like `im = zeros(256); im(128, 128) = 1;` etc. 256, 128 are just some arbitrary values. You should use the proper size and coordinates.

Comment: @dhanushka Well, I can't do this since the coordinates (x,y) are real values and not necessarily integers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I completely understand what you are trying to say, I was trying to proceed with what the following paper suggests and see by myself if it's legit to do so: " http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7045801 ".

Comment: Try this as an example: `x = linspace(0, pi, 100);plot(x, sin(x));ax = gca;ax.Visible = 'off';set(gcf,'color','w');im = frame2im(getframe(gcf));`. This way, you can extract your plot into an image matrix. Ref: [remove axes](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/360462-how-to-remove-axis-in-plot), [change bg color](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96159-how-can-i-change-the-background-color-from-gray-to-white-when-copying-a-figure-to-powerpoint), [plot to image](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/163764-how-do-i-convert-an-image-plot-to-a-matrix).